# Chrome extension popup losing focus?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When my popup is open, several special commands (using key combinations not available through the chrome.commands API) are utilized. The trouble is, when I open a file dialog and it closes again, the window loses focus, and all keys are lost. A click on the window is required for keys to work again.

Using `click()` does not work. Neither does `window.focus()`; How can I give focus back to my popup (while it's open) after creating an input file dialog, or whenever else the extension popup remains open for that matter?

Comment: Sounds like an inherent limitation of the browser UI. At least there's no special API for extensions in that regard.

Comment: @wOxxOm maybe I could add a button that users must click on after importing...